# Book where only women were left on Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

Book where there were only women left on the Earth. Someone found male DNA and there was a battle over whether they wanted to produce a male child. I don't remember much, but I remember someone left the lab with with the DNA.

It is from the late 70's or early 80's.

Answer (score 2):

["When It Changed" by Joanna Russ](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40791)

*Is not* on Earth; it *is* a planet colonized only by women.

*Is not* a book, but it *is* a short story nominated for Hugo and Nebula awards.

They do *not* find male DNA, but male DNA *does* come to them when the first male astronauts arrive.

I don't know that there is a "battle", but there *is* immediate internal and external struggle: if they do breed with the male astronauts, life as they knew it is over.

If your memory on the story is hazy, then this is a partial match for it.